# Number of ways picking up shoes not belonging to a pair

Tags: combinatorics

A closet contains 5 pairs of shoes.What is the number of ways in which 4 shoes can be chosen from it so that there will be no complete pair ?

My attempt : My attempt was to find out the total number of ways in which 4 shoes can be chosen out of ten and then subtract the number of ways in which at least one pair will be chosen that is $ 5* {8 \choose 2} $.
But this gives 70 as the answer , while the correct answer is 80. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: "the number of ways in which at least one pair will be chosen": you forgot to subtract the number of ways two pairs can be chosen, as you are counting those cases multiple times. (This is a simple application of the inclusion-exclusion principle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When subtracting the number of ways in which at least one pair is chosen, you double-counted the cases when you take exactly two pairs. You have to add again the number of ways in which you can take two pairs. Note that this number is ${5 \choose 2}=10$. So, you get your answer.

Comment: Please read above answers

Comment: @ArchisWelankar By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways of selecting four shoes from different pairs is $$\binom{10}{4} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{6}{0}$$ where $\binom{10}{4}$ represents the number of ways of selecting four of the ten shoes, $\binom{5}{1}$ represents the number of ways of selecting one pair, $\binom{8}{2}$ represents the number of ways of ways of choosing two of the remaining eight shoes, $\binom{5}{2}$ represents the number of ways of selecting two pairs, and $\binom{6}{0}$ is the number of ways of choosing none of the other $6$ shoes.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to first use permutations:

The first shoe can be chosen in $10$ ways, but to avoid pairs, for the next there are only $8$ choices, then $6$ choices, and so on.

Thus permutations of $4$ "non-pairs" $= 10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4$

But we are only interested in this *collection*, not their order, thus divide be $4!$

$\dfrac{10\cdot8\cdot6\cdot4}{4!} = 80$

Answer (score 2):

You can visualize it first:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 1 2 3 4 5

Now you can have a choice out of two in each column. For 4 pairs you choose first out of the pairs from number 1 to number 4. This $2^4=16$. We have 5 pair of shoes. The ways of choosing 4 out of 5 shoes of different pairs is ${5 \choose 4} =5$.  Therefore in total you have 80 ways of choosing 4 shoes of different pairs.

Comment: I would have said that to obtain four shoes from different pairs, we must choose $4$ of the five pairs, then choose one of the two shoes from each pair.  We can do the first task in $\binom{5}{4}$ ways and each of the latter tasks in $2$ ways, which yields your correct answer of $\binom{5}{4} \cdot 2^4$.